# How to simplify the product of two $\exp$ functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, signal-processing

It's been a while since I did any of this.  I have the following product: $\exp(-j2 \pi u|k|x) \cdot \exp(-j2 \pi v |k|x)$.  This seems like it is something that can be simplified, but how?  Note, that is not convolution, it is simple multiplication.  Thanks!

Comment: Just recall that $\exp(x)=e^x$. It immediately comes natural to manipulate $\exp(x)$.

Comment: Please: To use an asterisk for ordinary multiplication within $\TeX$ is uncouth and vulgar.  It amounts to eating mashed potatoes with your fingers when silverware is available.  Or to putting your face into the plate and eating like a horse from a a trough.  The asterisk is a workaround for occasions when you're restricted to the symbols on the keyboard and can't use a lower-case "x" because that's being otherwise used.  In $\TeX$ you can write $a\cdot b$ or $a\times b$ or $a\otimes b$, etc. etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $e^x\cdot e^y=e^{x+y}$, we get
$$
\exp(-j2 \pi u|k|x) \cdot \exp(-j2 \pi v |k|x)=\exp(-j2 \pi (u+v)|k|x)
$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\exp(-j2 \pi u|k|x) \cdot \exp(-j2 \pi v |k|x)=\exp\big(-j2\pi u|k|x-j2\pi v|k|x\big) $$

$$=\exp(-j2\pi (u+v)|k|x).$$

Exponentials obey $a^ba^c=a^{b+c}$ (though there can be branching issues for complex $a$).